# What does the define function do in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Sometimes I see code that looks like this in Angular:

```
define(['angular', 'module'], function (angular, module) {
  //...
});
```

What does this do? Whenever I've tried to search for "angularjs define" or "angularjs define function" I see results like "How to define a function in AngularJS" or "AngularJS Defined."

This happens with search engines, and typing this into the search box on the AngularJS website doesn't help either.

Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: I haven't seen that before, got a hit on it here though: http://jonathancreamer.com/require-js-packages-for-building-large-scale-angular-applications/

Comment: This article may help http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its probably because you're assuming its an Angular function.   I believe this is RequireJS.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: Thanks for the help, to you and everyone else!

Answer (score 2):

That is not AngularJS function but RequireJS module definition.

More about how can you use RequireJS AMD library with AngularJS - read here: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/